Local axis issues after separating mirrored objects
I'm currently working on a small robot model in Blender, which I built in multiple parts and mirrored using the "Mirror" modifier to ensure symmetry between the left and right wings (see the first image). Once I was happy with the model, I applied the modifiers and separated each wing so they would be individual objects (Ctrl + P > Selection).
Problem :
After separating the objects, I noticed that the geometry center for the left wing is still linked to the original wing (the right wing, as shown in the first image). I adjusted the geometry center for each wing to position it where I wanted (see the second image).
However, in doing this, the left wing has also inherited the axial (local or normal) properties of the right wing. This means the local axes of the left wing do not align correctly with its geometry, preventing me from performing independent rotations as desired (see the third image).
Questions :
Is there a way to recalculate or reset the local axes so that they align correctly with each wing individually, without inheriting the original wing's axes?
Did I miss a step when separating the objects or applying the modifier?
Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions ! On the left is what i have and on the right is what i want


Please add your images directly into your question rather than just providing links to them. You're more likely to get a reply if folks can see what you're talking about. How to upload an image to a post.

It would also help if you shared your Blend file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

@JohnEason I don’t think sharing the blend file is necessary. It’s pretty clear what happened. The original part(s) had some location and rotation transforms, and applying the mirror modifier(s) and separating the objects just left the new one(s) with the same transforms, unmirrored. Changing the location transforms via setting a new origin(s) did not affect the rotation transforms, and so here we have the issue.

@TheLabCat Fair enough. I agree that an armature wold certainly be the way to go.

Because character animation is usually done with an armature (in which the needed local axes are defined by the bones’ orientation), I recommend you just apply rotation for the objects (giving them all globally aligned axes), then set up an armature and skin the robot to it.
